# Nested optimization problems solving using mixed integer linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let us have two vectors of decision variables,
$\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$,
two linear objective functions,
$F \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right)$ and 
$f \left( \mathbf{x} \right)$,
and two sets of linear constraints,
$G_i \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) \leq 0$ and 
$g_j \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \leq 0$, where
$i=1,2,\dotsc,n$ and $j=1,2,\dotsc,m$.

The problem to be solved is minimization of $F$:
$$
\begin{array}{rll}
\min & F \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) & \\
\text{subject to:} & G_i \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) \leq 0, & i=1,2,\dotsc,n \\
& g_j \left( \mathbf{x} \right) \leq 0, & j=1,2,\dotsc,m
\end{array}
$$
but with the additional requirement that the values of $\mathbf{x}$ must be such that the value of $f \left( \mathbf{x} \right)$ is minimal possible for a given set of $\mathbf{y}$.

In my case, some variables of $\mathbf{x}$ are continuous and some are binary, while all $\mathbf{y}$ variables are binary.

Can this problem be solved using mixed integer linear programming (MILP), *e.g.* the branch and cut method and, if yes, how to formulate it?

I can solve such problems combining metaheuristics (*e.g.* genetic algorithms or simulated annealing), to find $\mathbf{y}$, and MILP to find $\mathbf{x}$ for each examined set of $\mathbf{y}$ values. I would, however, prefer using MILP for the entire problem, if possible.

Update. In order to clarify the problem, I'll explain its background. This problem aims at optimizing the energy supply plant. The $\mathbf{y}$ binary variables define the structure of the plant, *i.e.* determine if a component is going to be installed or not. The $\mathbf{x}$ variables define the operation of the plant, *i.e.* the operating modes of all components. If a component is not installed (corresponding $y=0$), than it cannot operate (corresponding $x=0$). The objective function $F \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right)$ might be related to *e.g.* some financial parameter, environmental impact, energy consumption, plant reliability *etc.* or even a linear combination of all of them. The objective function $f \left( \mathbf{x} \right)$ represents variable operation-only-related costs. To make this simpler, I want to find $\min F \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right)$ under the assumption that the plant will always operate in the cost-optimal manner (*i.e.* with $\min f$).

Comment: The inner problem doesn't depend on $y$ at all. Why not just solve it to obtain $x$, and then plug it into the larger problem to get a problem in $y$?

Comment: Because that might lead to the violation of some of the constraints $G_i \left( \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \right) \leq 0$.

Comment: If the optimal value of the inner problem is unique, then there's nothing you can do about it. If it is not unique, then find its optimal value $p$, and just add the constraint $f(x)\leq p$ to the larger problem. Or maybe $f(x)\leq p+\epsilon$ to give it some breathing room.

Comment: If neither of those options does what you want, then I would argue you're not actually trying to solve the model as you have described, and you may need to re-think your description.

Comment: @MichaelGrant. I have added the additional explanation to the original post now. My primary objective is to minimize $F$, but under the assumption that $x$ values are such that $f$ is minimal. The $x$ values are constrained with the $y$ values.

Comment: I understand the explanation but I am afraid it is still insufficient. You haven't rewritten your inner problem, which is still independent of $y$. So the correct answer, to the problem *as written*, remains: solve the inner problem first, and plug the result into the outer problem, and solve for $y$.

Comment: It seems to me, then, that your primary problem here is finding a concrete mathematical explanation for what you're trying to do. Solve that, and I suspect it will be straightforward to determine how to solve it.

Comment: @MichaelGrant. My main problem is to mathematically describe what I'm trying to solve in the manner suitable for using MILP. Maybe defining the inner problem wasn't a good idea in this case (it works when the problem is decomposed and when I combine metaheuristics and MILP). And I'm aware that I could penalize the objective function $F$ or, as you have written, minimize $F+\lambda f$. But this might put to much or to little weight on the cost function. I wonder if somehow I could express the requirement that $f \left( \mathbf{x} \right)$ must be minimal in a form of a constraint.

Comment: I deleted the multiobjective idea after considering more closely what you're trying to do. Really, the problem here is that $x$ is a *function* of $y$. For any *fixed* $y$, $x$ is the solution to this problem:\begin{array}{lll}\text{minimize}&f(x)\\\text{subject to}&G_i(x,y)\leq 0&i=1,2,\dots,n\\&g_j(x)\leq 0&j=1,2,\dots,m\end{array}If we say that $g(y)$ is the solution to that problem, then you're reduced to minimizing $F(g(y),y)$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant. Exactly.

Comment: OK, fellow readers! Perhaps our discussion will help one of you in assisting MSt here.

Comment: Unfortunately I know what to do for the continuous case, but it really won't map to the binary case.

Comment: @MichaelGrant. Can you explain your idea for the continuous case, please? It probably will not solve my problem, but I'd like to know, for curiosity.

Comment: OK, I'll offer it as an answer.

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, my idea doesn't work after all. It involved finding the dual of the pricing model and replacing $x$ with the dual variables, but I can't get it to work here.